# Is it possible not to use div all the time?

Tags: html

I am new to Html and as I was watching tutorials on YouTube I encountered with author all the time using div, that is, in the header section he wanted to use h1, p and image. The code:

```
   <header id="showcase">
<div class="content">
<img src="img/action-america-architecture-378570.jpg" alt="The City">
<div class="heading">
    <h1>Mirasan</h1>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Deserunt sequi placeat rerum maxime eius, impedit molestiae totam! Ipsum ex numquam nobis nisi necessitatibus fugit laudantium natus, vel facilis, nemo quisquam.</p>
</div>
</div>

    </header>
```

As you can see, h1, p and image was firstly put inside div class="content" then h1 and p were then put into respective divs. My question is Is it ok to put h1. p and image into header and remove all divs from the header like content, heading and text. Like this:

```
    <header id="showcase">
<img src="img/action-america-architecture-378570.jpg" alt="The City">
    <h1>Mirasan</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Deserunt sequi placeat rerum maxime eius, impedit molestiae totam! Ipsum ex numquam nobis nisi necessitatibus fugit laudantium natus, vel facilis, nemo quisquam.</p>
    </header>
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK but a `div` is a way to group things together (for various reasons, likely for applying a common look and feel via Cascading Style Sheets, aka `CSS`)  - for a simple web page, you don't *have* to have the extra `div`s but for more complex site, you want to organize your content.

Comment: @ochi, by grouping things together you mean div with id of content holding h1, p and image but how about divs for h1 and p. What is the aim for using div for h1 and p Aren't those divs redundant or?

Comment: All those divs have a class which means they may have CSS or JS acting on them. You may want to be careful of that before removing them.

Comment: @jwebb, ok, but if I want to give some css or js to h1 and p  is it also possible to just remove divs and give respective class or id to h1 and p? I hope for your reply :)

Comment: Yes you can add your own, but why are those divs with classes there in the first place? I assume this is a site that was built by someone before you? People don't usually add classes for no reason. So I'm just saying that you should make sure that it doesn't break the existing CSS before you take it out. Maybe search the css for rules for those clases (i.e. .content{}, etc)

Comment: @jwebb OP mentioned the code comes from a YouTube tutorial

Comment: @ochi still it seems strange to put a class on a div if they weren't going to apply CSS rules to those classes, or JS...

Comment: @ochi, sorry dude just last thing, I wonder since header is also a container Is it ok if I remove div class="content", you, know, header also groups h1, p and image together. Or header  is better to be used in a declarative way, that is, to tell browser that this is header and that is it. I hope it is clear :)

Comment: @jwebb we don't which step of the tutorial this code shows up, nor we know if this is all the code there is to said tutorial

Comment: The `header` is a semantic container while the `<div class="content">` is tying a CSS rule to a non-semantic container.  There is no right-wrong here. It depends on your intent with those containers.   At this point, it really is up to the author (i.e. you or the tutorial's) on how you want to group/represent your content

Comment: What about posting a link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZv8YHYUHTU&t=802s

Comment: @ochi of course more information might affect the question. And it's still reasonable to say that if you don't why a div with a class is there, and you haven't seen all of the code and aren't aware of what is referencing it, then you should be careful about removing it without checking

Comment: @jwebb, ok dude I really appreciate your kind recommendation, you and "@ochi" saved my day :)

Comment: The question is not why a `div` is there... it's more generic than that... In the tutorials's particular case, it might be relevant to keep the `div`s - I understood OP is questioning the need to have them at all (in all cases) - *shrugs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of those `divs` as containers (just like a `p` is a container for your text and `h1` is a container for your title).

These containers (`p`, `h1`) are semantic, they mean something - a paragraph, a title. However, `div`s are more generic containers (not-semantic).

They are redundant only if they add nothing to the page - as I mentioned in my comment, usually they are added as grouping mechanism (i.e. the `h1`, the `img` and the `p` are related and are kept together by the `div` container) - grouping them like so allows you to define a `CSS` rule and apply the same rule to all containers of the same `.class`

In your sample code, one could apply the `.text` class to the `p` tag directly, like:

```
<p class="text">lorem ipsum... </p>
```

Same concept to the `h1` tag, like:

```
<h1 class="heading">Mirasan</h1>
```

Why the original author chose to wrap them in a container, we don't know.  The `div`s only contain one element (either a `p` or an `h1`) so the author is not grouping elements. In this case, it does seem redundant.

Comment: clean, exact and simply great answer, thank you dude :)

Comment: glad I could help... :)